MediaWiki : #arraymap doesn't work in a model call
I have this array : courant : Gothique,Néo-roman,Ottonien
I tried to use this #arraymap to change its form :
{{#if: {{{courant|}}} |
{{#vardefine:num|0}}
{{#arraymap:{{{courant|}}}|,|@@@|{{#vardefine:num|{{#expr:{{#var:num}}+1}}}}<nowiki>|</nowiki>courant{{#var:num}}=@@@|\n}}
|}}

When I just print it in a <p> balise, it shows this (which is perfect):
|courant1=Gothique|courant2=Néo-roman|courant3=Ottonien
But when I put it there :
{{Bouton_recherche_avancée
|pays={{{pays|}}}
|ville={{{ville|}}}
|quartier={{{quartier|}}}
|sous-quartier={{{sous-quartier|}}}
|rue={{{rue|}}}
|personne={{{personne|}}}
|source={{{source|}}}
|structure={{{structure|}}}
|{{#if: {{{courant|}}} |
{{#vardefine:num|0}}
{{#arraymap:{{{courant|}}}|,|@@@|{{#vardefine:num|{{#expr:{{#var:num}}+1}}}}<nowiki>|</nowiki>courant{{#var:num}}=@@@|\n}}
|}}
|date_début={{{date_début|}}}
|date_fin={{{date_fin|}}}
|type_événement={{{type|}}}
|mh={{{mh|}}}
|ismh={{{ismh|}}}
|acr={{{acr|}}}
|unesco={{{unesco|}}}
}}

It does not show anything (maybe it's related to the  in some way)
Here's where the code is from :
Modèle:Recherche avancée
Here's where I want to use it :
Recherche avancée
and here's what it's trying to call :
Modèle:Bouton-recherche-avancée
if you have any on how to make this work or how I can do it in an other way than #arraymap that makes me avoid 

You should no longer rely on the Variables extension. You cannot guarantee that a variable will be set before ir is read.
Having courant1, courant2, ... courantn parameters in your template is a bad practice. I suggest that you redefine tha template so that it splits courant by comma and processes the chunks. It may require Lua.

I have found myself a solution. I let go of the dream of having a loop and did the lazy method :
{{Bouton_recherche_avancée
|text1=Afficher en liste
|pays={{{pays|}}}
|ville={{{ville|}}}
|quartier={{{quartier|}}}
|sous-quartier={{{sous-quartier|}}}
|rue={{{rue|}}}
|personne={{{personne|}}}
|source={{{source|}}}
|structure={{{structure|}}}
|courant1={{#if:{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|0|}}|{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|0|}}}}
|courant2={{#if:{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|1|}}|{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|1|}}}}
|courant3={{#if:{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|2|}}|{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|2|}}}}
|courant4={{#if:{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|3|}}|{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|3|}}}}
|courant5={{#if:{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|4|}}|{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|4|}}}}
|courant6={{#if:{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|5|}}|{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|5|}}}}
|courant7={{#if:{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|6|}}|{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|6|}}}}
|courant8={{#if:{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|7|}}|{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|7|}}}}
|courant9={{#if:{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|8|}}|{{#explode:{{{courant|}}}|,|8|}}}}
|date_début={{{date_début|}}}
|date_fin={{{date_fin|}}}
|type_événement={{{type|}}}
|mh={{{mh|}}}
|ismh={{{ismh|}}}
|acr={{{acr|}}}
|unesco={{{unesco|}}}
}}

but now it works and there shoudn't be more than 9 courant

Using variables is probably fine and you likely don't need to worry about it. See: https://river.me/blog/variables-and-parsoid/
However, what you are trying to do is fundamentally not going to work as intended.
You're outputting effectively this code:
{{Bouton_recherche_avancée{{!}}courant1=val1{{!}}courant2=val2{{!}}<!-- etc -->}}

Where there are {{!}} instead of |. {{!}} is going to be a literal pipe character, and NOT the special character used to separate template args from each other.
What you can do instead is like:
{{#arraymaptemplate:{{{courant|a,b,c}}}|VardefineCourant|,|}}

At Template:VardefineCourant:
{{#vardefine:courant<!--
   -->{{#vardefineecho:num|{{#expr:{{#var:num|0}}+1}}<!-- end vde -->}}|{{{1}}}<!-- end vd -->}}

Then at Template:Bouton_recherche_avancée you can use {{#var:courant1}}, {{#var:courant2}}, etc instead of {{{courant1|}}}, {{{courant2|}}}, etc, as you have them now
